# How can I change Font Awesome icon and Text on condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

component.html

```
<i [title]="CardData.quantity > 1 || _ShippingVariable > 1 ? CannotShip : FreeShipping" 
   [ngClass]="{'fa': true,'fa-youtube': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE',}">
</i>
```

ShippingVairable is Coming From component.ts

So what I am trying to do that is _ShippingVariable=0 then i will get  "(CrossFontAwesomeIcon)CannotShip:It should be in red color".
And if _ShippingVariable=1 then I will get (CheckFontAwesomeIcon)FreeShipping:It should be in green color".

And Please Any resource material or tutorial where I can clear my Angular NgClass because I want to change CSS dynamically on conditions.

Comment: How do you know that `_ShippingVariable` is coming properly? Do you get the right title? What *are* you getting? and you have several typos (_ShippingVariable > 1, not >0). Please edit the question for clarity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its a simple understanding: Take a look at this

```
// In component.ts file lets say you have 2 boolean flags
boolFlag1: boolean = true;
boolFlag2: boolean = false;

// In HTML / CSS you can have any class

// You want a class 'class-1' to be present all the times, 'class-2' to be present when boolFlag1 is true and 'class-3' when boolFlag2 is true

Then you can do something like this

<div 
   class="class-1" // This class will be present at all times irrespective of the conditions
  [class.class-2]="boolFlag1" // Class2 will be applied when boolFlag1 is true
  [class.class-3]="boolFlag2" // Class3 will be applied when boolFlag2 is true
>
</div>

// In the above example, class-3 will not be applied since i made boolFlag2 to be false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this rather than [ngClass]

```
//  Your way
<i [title]="CardData.quantity > 1 || _ShippingVariable > 1 ? CannotShip : FreeShipping" 
   [ngClass]="{'fa': true,'fa-youtube': socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE',}">
</i>

// My suggestion
<i [title]="CardData.quantity > 1 || _ShippingVariable > 1 ? CannotShip : FreeShipping" 
   [class.fa-youtube]="socialMediaLink.socialMediaType === 'YOUTUBE'"
   class="fa" // Seems like you always want this class so dont put that in conditions
>
</i>
```

Comment: brothere where i can learn about [class.fa-youtube] and all that icons and class

Comment: Brother Now I know the [class] and [ngClass] now Thanks for your help i did this like

Answer (score -1):

Brother Srikar Phani Kumar Marti Now I know the [class] and [ngClass] now Thanks for your help i did this like

```
 <i 
      [class.text-success]="CardData.quantity > 1 || _ProductQuantity > 1"
      [ngClass]="{'fa': true,'far fa-check-square': CardData.quantity > 1 || 
 _ProductQuantity > 1, 'far fa-times-circle': CardData.quantity < 1 || 
 _ProductQuantity < 1}"
      [class.text-danger]="CardData.quantity < 1 || _ProductQuantity < 1"
      >
      {{CardData.quantity < 1 || _ProductQuantity < 1 ? "Cannot
      Ship" : "Free
      Shipping"}}
      </i>
```

```
///// By Srikar

// Please remember you can do this too to keep the HTML clean and neat.

// in component.ts file, create a variable for the classes

conditionalClasses = {
     'fa': true,
     'far fa-check-square': CardData.quantity > 1 || _ProductQuantity > 1, 
     'far fa-times-circle': CardData.quantity < 1 || _ProductQuantity < 1
}

// in HTML file, you can do this too! 
<i 
    [class.text-success]="CardData.quantity > 1 || _ProductQuantity > 1"
    [ngClass]="conditionalClasses"
    [class.text-danger]="CardData.quantity < 1 || _ProductQuantity < 1"
>
    {{
       (CardData.quantity < 1 || _ProductQuantity < 1) 
          ? "Cannot Ship" 
          : "Free Shipping"
    }}
</i>
```

Comment: Brother Do i need to define conditionalClass in css?